# How to check Div is disabled onclick in JS

Tags: javascript, html, magento2

I want to check the *div* whose class name is *swatch-option* and which is coming dynamically and there is not only single div with this class there is a lot of div with the same class now I want to check that if one of these div is disable and also click on that div then it shows me a message. let me inform you That I want to do this in **javascript** not in **Jquery**. the code I tried is

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var e = document.getElementsByClassName("swatch-option");
    e.onClick = MyFunction;

    function MyFunction()
    {
    if (e.disabled == true) {
        alert('working');
    }else{
        alert('not Working');
    }
    }
</script>
```

I also tried

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {
    var e = document.getElementsByClassName("disabled");
    e.onClick = function MyFunction()
    {
    if (e.disabled == true) {
        alert('Working');
    }else{
        alert('not Working');
    }
    }
}
</script>
```

but still not working

[image: The div on which I want to perform an action]

[image]
the circle I made around the colors is disabled so when I clicked on these colors then it shows a message *out of Stock*

Comment: Dear @Asad Khan we can disabled only form elements i.e. input,select,buttons etc.
We can hide,remove etc a div.Are you got the point...?

Comment: actually it shows the colors and the colors who are not available in the inventory then it make them disabled so I just simple want the product which is not available in the inventory then it needs to show a message not available in the inventory sort of message

Comment: then you just hide or replace text in that div.

Comment: As correctly pointed by @AsadKhan, disabled property is only available for form elements. In your case, as far as i understand, I believe you need to have a separate click behavior for inventory that are not available. As stated by you, the colors are different. So instead of checking for the disabled property in your handler function, check for the color instead.

Comment: no I dont want to remove but when the customer select the specific color which is *out of stock* then it shows a message that product is out of stock

Comment: @Asad Khan then use $("#your-div-id").text("out of stock");

Comment: check by updated question

Answer (score 0):

Div elements cannot be `disabled`. Only form elements like buttons and inputs. You can simulate a disabled state however by setting some class name on the div and then styling that class appropriately. Or alternatively you can change your divs into buttons and style away the default browser stylings. Note that your code as it is won't work anyway because:

```
var e = document.getElementsByClassName("swatch-option"); // returns an array of elements
e.onClick = MyFunction; // e is not an element it's an array, and also MyFunction has not been declared yet.
```

If you use a class for disabled, you could use `document.getElementsByClassName("disabled")` to get the elements which are disabled. If you set the disabled attribute on a button, then no clicks will be processed, so there's nothing more to do. I suggest that approach.

Comment: so Sir I need to find it like `document.getElementsByClassName("disabled")` so I want to apply the condition if class is disabled then... so how can I apply the **if** condition

Comment: If you get the disabled elements using getElementsByClassName, you can attach a handler function to onClick which does what you want - no if needed since it's only applied to the disabled divs.

Comment: can you please update your answer since I'm really noob in JS

Answer (score 0):

***If the element is disabled, it does not respond to user actions, it cannot be focused, and the command event will not fire. In the case of form elements, it will not be submitted.***

You can try with some color like the following way:

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll(".swatch-option");
Array.from(els).forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('click', function MyFunction(){
    if (this.style.color == 'gray') {
      alert('working');
    }else{
      alert('not Working');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="swatch-option" style="color:gray">swatch-option1</div>
<div class="swatch-option">swatch-option2</div>
<div class="swatch-option" style="color:gray">swatch-option3</div>
<div class="swatch-option">swatch-option4</div>
```

Comment: for disable what should I do is there is any solution for that?

Comment: @AsadKhan, *disabled* attribute is only for form elements like inputs, also you can not click on any disabled element....

Comment: yeah it is an input... you can check it in my updated question

Comment: @AsadKhan, images are not helpful, please share the sample html:)